# How to Install UpWork on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit?

Tags: server, 16.04

When I try to install the `upwork_amd64.deb` package in *Software*, it shows:

> Could not find 'upwork'

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you have already downloaded the .deb file from Upwork website and have problems installing it with the Software Center try using the terminal command:

```
sudo dpkg -i upwork_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

you can install like below steps:

1. GO to this url https://www.upwork.com/downloads
2. Download the .Debian-based 64-bit (Standard) version
3. Open Terminal [ctrl+alt+t]
4. GO to Downloads folder: `cd Downloads`
5. Run these commands

> ```
> sudo dpkg -i upwork_amd64.deb
> sudo apt-get -f install
> ```

After finish the processing let’s search this app at start menu.
Happy Freelancing!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the package name you downloaded. 
For me, it is `upwork_5.5.0.11_amd64.deb`, and I install it as follows:

```
sudo dpkg -i upwork_5.5.0.11_amd64.deb
```

... it works.